# How to replace the string which has passed in procedure while using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Can some one help me how to use the string inside a string? I need to use something without bound variables because I am passing all the input parameters from a procedure which I am using in my real requirement, so the values are fixed.

```
create or replace procedure Sample( rowsize number )
is
    v_result varchar2(100);
    v_str varchar2(200);
begin
    v_str := 'Select rtrim(legl_ent_name) || '' | '' ||rtrim(legl_ent_prd_grp) as heirarchy from legl_ent_regn where rownum < rowsize';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_str ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rowsize);

end;
/
```

I'm getting the error below when I run the procedure.

```
BEGIN 
dbms_output.enable(); 
Sample(2); 
END;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "ROWSIZE": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "RATABASE.SAMPLE", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

Comment: Would this work? ``v_str := 'Select ... where rownum < ' || to_char(rowsize) ;``

Comment: "need to use without bind variable because i am passing all the input parameters from procedure which i am using in my real requirement, so the values are fixed." — that doesn't quite seem to make sense. The answer posted uses a bind variable, or you can use @ypercubeᵀᴹ's suggestion but surely you have the option? If the values are really fixed you could just hard-code them into the quesy?

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace procedure Sample(rowsize number)
is
    v_result varchar2(100);
    v_str varchar2(200);
begin
    v_str := 'Select rtrim(legl_ent_name) || '' | '' ||rtrim(legl_ent_prd_grp) as heirarchy from legl_ent_regn where rownum < :1';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_str USING rowsize;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rowsize);
end;
```